# Formato de array php

Tags: php, mysql, array

otra vez aquí pienso que es algo facil pero aun no encuentro como resolverlo, necesito tener un array en el siguiente formato al terminar de hacer la consulta mysql ya que le quiero agregar un index por fila.

```
$procesos = array();
    $sql = 'SELECT *  FROM banco WHERE activa=1 AND delop=1';
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    $procesos = [];
    $index=0;
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $index++;
        $fila['index']=$index;
        switch ($fila ['tipo_cuenta']) {
            case 1 :
                $fila ['tipo_cuenta'] = 'Presidente';
                break;
            case 2 :
                $fila ['tipo_cuenta'] = 'Ayudante';
                break;
        }
        array_push($procesos, $fila);
    }
    echo json_encode($procesos);
```

Este es el resultado que quisiera tener pero sale diferente

```
{"data":[[index1,17,"Banco numero 1","8","2202363030","Quevedo"],[index2,21,"Banco numero 2","13","10036515050","Ceibos"]]}
```

Comment: Amigo siento no haberte podido ayudarte pero también debes entender que no todos estamos conectados a esa hora, aproximadamente a las 3:00 de la mañana a esa hora seguramente estén durmiendo como es mi caso ya que soy de España, luego me alegro que lo hayas solucionado , pero por favor pon tu solución como respuesta par a posibles problemas similares para otros usuarios, saludos

Comment: A las 4 de la mañana exactamente según mis cálculos a esa hora en esta paginas pocas personas que sepa lo que te ocurre estén conectados : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/203